# Как очистить содержимое GroupBox'а в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel, qgroupbox

Есть код, который задает `lable`, они в свою очередь хранятся внутри `groupbox`.

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки `clear` содержимое `groupbox` полностью очищалось?

**main.py**:

```
import untitled
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import numpy as np
import sys


class Testik(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, untitled.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Testik, self).__init__(parent)
        # self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.list = []

        self.label.hide()
        self.label_2.hide()
        self.label_3.hide()
        self.label_4.hide()
        self.label_5.hide()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn)
        self.btn_clear.clicked.connect(self.clear)

    def btn(self):
        for i in range(5):
            item = np.random.randint(0, 10)
            self.list.append(item)
        self.label.setText(str(self.list[0]))
        self.label_2.setText(str(self.list[1]))
        self.label_3.setText(str(self.list[2]))
        self.label_4.setText(str(self.list[3]))
        self.label_5.setText(str(self.list[4]))
        self.label.show()
        self.label_2.show()
        self.label_3.show()
        self.label_4.show()
        self.label_5.show()

    def clear(self):
        self.groupBox.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Testik()
    ui.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**untitled.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(344, 327)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.btn_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName("btn_clear")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_clear)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 344, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.btn_clear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "clear"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "List"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виджет QGroupBox предоставляет контейнер с рамкой группового окна с заголовком, в который вы помещаете `QLabel'ы` и очищать надо `QLabel'ы`.

Не совсем уверен, что правильно понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать, но попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# ??? import untitled
# from untitled import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(344, 327)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        self.btn_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName("btn_clear")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_clear)
        
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 344, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.btn_clear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "clear"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "List"))
        '''
# ???        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
# ???        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
# ???        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
# ???        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
# ???        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        '''

class Testik(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Testik, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        '''
# ???        self.list = []
        
# ???        self.label.hide()
# ???        self.label_2.hide()
# ???        self.label_3.hide()
# ???        self.label_4.hide()
# ???        self.label_5.hide()
        '''
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn)
        self.btn_clear.clicked.connect(self.clear)

    def btn(self):
# ???        for i in range(5):
# ???            item = np.random.randint(0, 10, 5)
# ???            self.list.append(item)

# -------------------------------------> v <-------------------------------
        _list = np.random.randint(0, 10, 5)
        #print(f'{_list}') 
        
#        self.label.setText(str(_list[0]))
# ---------------> vvvvvv <------------------------------------------------
        self.label.setNum(_list[0])
        self.label_2.setNum(_list[1])
        self.label_3.setNum(_list[2])
        self.label_4.setNum(_list[3])
        self.label_5.setNum(_list[4])
        
        '''
# ???        self.label.show()
# ???        self.label_2.show()
# ???        self.label_3.show()
# ???        self.label_4.show()
# ???        self.label_5.show()
        '''

    def clear(self):
#        self.groupBox.clear()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        objectList = self.groupBox.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLabel)
        for obj in objectList:
            obj.clear()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Testik()
    ui.show()
# ???    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]